# Android: Programmatically defined view in main.xml file?

Tags: android

I'm still relatively new to android programming, so please explain things that may seem obvious.

I have defined a custom view programmatically:

```
class RenderView extends View{
```

I would like this view to play nice with some TextViews etc, so I want to include my RenderView in the main.xml file. How do I get the main.xml file to recognize my custom view?

Moreover, if my RenderView has parameters with it's constructor, how would that work? I assume I can't pass parameters directly from the main.xml file, but then how do I get the main.xml file to recognize a view that I have created programmatically?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as other views. You can either use the graphical layout, for dragging and dropping your custom views, from the "Custom Views" tab of the pallete that shows all the widgets.

The XML that you need to add would look something like this.

```
 <com.package.RenderView andrdoi:layout_width="wrap_content" .....>
 </com.package.RenderView>
```

For passing custom parameters, you will need to first create them. Here's the link that explains more about it.

http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/